# msal plugin is undefined

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, msal.js

I follow the git post below to implement MSAL in Cordova iOS application but it seems like cordova plugin is null.

https://github.com/wrobins/cordova-plugin-msal

This is always null

```
let isAvailable = typeof(cordova.plugins.msalPlugin) !== "undefined";
```

I get this error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'msalPlugin')
Not allowed to launch '' because a user gesture is required.

Comment: You have to check msalPlugin present in plugins folder and confirm Cordova.js present in www folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I have face some issue, I am using out systems and integrated this plugin and try to run o browser then getting some error

`So For Resolution`

**I have installed my app on android phone then run application. It is working fine.**

In short, you need to install app on mobile either it is iOS/android phone **Because cordova is only available on phone not on browser**